# Async method locks user interface

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, avalonia

As far as I know async method won't lock user interface. At least it seems to work most of the time. But here it doesn't, and I can't figure out why. It's Avalonia MVVM application. Here is the code:

```cs
public class MainWindowViewModel : ReactiveValidationObject
{
   public MainWindowViewModel()
   {
      OnRunClick = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask(
                () => OnRun(),
                this.IsValid());
   }
   public ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> OnRunClick { get; }
   
   private async Task OnRun()
   {
      await Dispatcher.UIThread.InvokeAsync(() =>
      {
         DoSomethingForVeryLongTime();
      }
   }
}
```

When button is clicked `OnRunClick` is called, and then user interface stops responding as long as `DoSomethingForVeryLongTime` runs. Which is not possible to happen, because async ensures interface is still active, yet it happens.

Comment: You aren't using an asynchronous method at all. `UIThread.InvokeAsync` runs `DoSomethingForVeryLongTime` on the UI thread, as the name says. What is `DoSomethingForVeryLongTime` and why are you running it on the UI thread? Why not use `await Task.Run(DoSomethingForVeryLongTime);`?

Comment: You explicitly invoke `DoSomethingForVeryLongTime` on UI thread, so no wonder UI stops responding.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos await Task.Run doesn't function in desktop applications because it triggers an exception - `System.InvalidOperationException: Call from invalid thread`

Comment: @Walter125 it runs perfectly well - that's one of the primary use cases. Web apps use different threads per request already. Almost all desktop apps use it since 2012. Th. The error is caused by attempts to modify the UI from the background thread, which isn't allowed in any OS, no matter how you invoke the method. You need to modify `DoSomethingForVeryLongTime` so it *doesn't* try to modify the UI. Post your code

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos `DoSomethingForVeryLongTime` doesn't modify the UI because it's algorithm from entirely different project. And I'm pretty sure no one will be reading 2300 lines of code.

Comment: If it doesn't access UI then there should be no "Call from invalid thread" thrown when you run it via `await Task.Run(DoSomethingForVeryLongTime)`

Comment: @Walter125 if you want help to fix your code you need to show *which* code modifies the UI. That code can't run in the background. There's no way around this

Comment: @Evk it's method from different project so it can't modify the UI, because there is no UI.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i think these 2300 lines of code can be shortened to `Task.Delay(enoughMsToLastForAtLeast5Minutes)`.

Comment: Well then you should create another question with updated code which actually runs `DoSomethingForVeryLongTime` and ask why it throws "Call from invalid thread" when there is no UI access there (and include stack trace of exception)

Comment: @Evk i think i know why it happens. Avalonia application subscribes to a bunch of events in `DoSomethingForVeryLongTime` to inform user about progress. But it looks like such thing is simply not doable, because then you have to lock interface to avoid thread exception, and when interface is locked you can't inform the user about changes.

Comment: @Walter125 So this is mixing two different "async" concepts: Events and Tasks-Based. You need to be careful then, anyway because the two do not get along _very_ well. It's doable but has its quirks.

Comment: Just use that UIThread.Invoke inside event handlers then, only to update UI. Don't use it to run the whole thing.

Comment: @Walter125 you can have asynchronous event handlers. If you use MVVM, you can modify data in the background and then replace the VM properties if not the entire VM itself. This will trigger a UI update. If you make a lot of modifications to a VM *freeze* UI notifications until the modifications are done. Even with async, 5 UI notifications in 1 second will waste CPU and annoy users.

Comment: @Fildor it is doable in theory, but not in my case. `DoSomethingForVeryLongTime` is in different project and is untouchable now, but in theory it can be rewritten to run one iteration at a time, and then update the UI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code runs `DoSomethingForVeryLongTime` on the UI thread, not a background thread. It issues the call asynchronously but the actual call still runs on the UI thread.

**Running something in the background**

To actually run in the background, use `Task.Run` :

```
private async Task OnRun()
{
   await Task.Run(DoSomethingForVeryLongTime);      
}
```

**Updating the UI with async/await**

Background methods can't modify the UI though, no matter how they're invoked. Execution needs to return to the UI thread somehow. That's what `await` does in the first place.

If `DoSomethingForVeryLongTime` can be split into background and UI parts, the background parts can run in the background using `Task.Run`. Execution will return to the UI thread with `await`. For example

```
private async Task OnRun()
{
    await DoSomethingForVeryLongTime();      
}

async Task DoSomethingForVeryLongTime()
{
    for int(i=0;i<1000;i++)
    {
        //Process in another thread background
        await Task.Run(()=>DoSomethingExpensive(i));
        //Return to the UI thread and update it
        UpdateProgressBar(i);
    }
    lblStatus.Text="Complete";
}
```

**Updating the UI using IProgress**

Another option is to use the [IProgress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iprogress-1?view=net-7.0) interface and the [Progress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.progress-1?view=net-7.0) implementation to report progress from a background thread. `Progress<T>` calls a callback method for each message in the thread it was created in :

```
record FileProgress(string Name, int Index, int Total);

//This will run in the UI thread
void UpdateProgress(FileProgress fp)
{
...
}

private async Task OnRun()
{
    //pg is created in the UI thread
    var pg=new Progress<FileProgress>(UpdateProgress);

    await Task.Run(()=>DoSomethingForVeryLongTime(pg));      
}

async Task DoSomethingForVeryLongTime(IProgress<FileProgress> progress)
{
    for int(i=0;i<1000;i++)
    {
        ...
        //Return to the UI thread and update it
        progress.Report(new FileProgress(fileName,i,1000);
    }
}
```

**Avoiding Task.Run**

`Task.Run` may not be needed at all if the "long runinng" work is an asynchronous operation, like waiting for a database response, an HTTP call or any IO operations. In this case we can use the asynchronous version of the operation, and get back to the UI thread when the operation completes.

Let's say we need to make multiple HTTP calls which can take several seconds. We can use HttpClient.GetAsync for this :

```
private async Task OnRun()
{
    await DoSomethingForVeryLongTime();      
}

async Task DoSomethingForVeryLongTime()
{
    using var connection=new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
    foreach(var url in _urls)
    {
        var response=await _httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);
        await connection.ExecuteAsync(@"insert MyTable(url,response) values (@url, @response)",
            new { url,response });
        UpdateProgressBar(url);
    }
    lblStatus.Text="Complete";
}
```

This example uses [Dapper](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper) to avoid the typical database boilerplate code. Dapper will open and close a connection as needed, so we avoid having a connection open while retrieving HTTP responses.

Comment: Since `Task.Run()` will run on thread pool thread, I'd say it's not a good idea to use it for something that runs for very long time.

Comment: @Evk we don't know what that method actually does. We only have a cross-thread exception to go by, and persuading the OP to actually show us the UI-modifying code. Adding more info would only lead to confusion. Besides, there are a lot of options depending on the actual "something" - perhaps it's a database call and doesn't need `Task.Run`? A loop with `Sleep` that can be replaced by a timer?